# How can I use Microsoft Graph API to get Application by appId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

After reading [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/application), I found we can get applications by using this API, but seems it doesn't contain all applications like 'Graph explorer', 'Skype Web Experience On Office 365', 'Office.com'...etc, so do we have any API can request that applications information?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try listing the service principals? Docs are at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/serviceprincipal_list

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals`

The graph explorer app is listed there for example:
[image]
[image]

Note the `appId` field is probably what you're interested in and you can filter by that field with a $filter query parameter:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq 'de8bc8b5-d9f9-48b1-a8ad-b748da725064'`

Comment: I know this API, but this API can't find service like 'Skype Web Experience On Office 365' or 'Office.com'

Comment: I don't think appId is supported as a filter clause, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-beta#properties
I get "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'appId' of resource 'ServicePrincipal'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the application endpoint. For example your call would be:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$filter=appId eq '6dbefcdc-a7bb-4789-bcd1-680ef661e3e9'
```